# which one is wrong?

Tags: c, syntax, function-pointers, grammar

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {int a; int b; int c;} F;
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int (*ptr)(F*);
} A;

int set_a(F * obj){
    obj->a = 1;
}
int main(){
    F a;
    A b;
    b.a = 0;
    b.ptr = set_a;
    b.ptr(&a);
    printf("%d",a.a);

    getchar();
}
```

this seems correct

but why

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int (*ptr)(A*);
} A;

int set_a(A * obj){
    obj->a = 1;
}
int main(){
    A a;
    a.a = 0;
    a.ptr = set_a;
    a.ptr(&a);
    printf("%d",a.a);

    getchar();
}
```

this is incorrect? and

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int (*ptr)(A);
} A;

int set_a(A * obj){
    obj->a = 1;
}
int main(){
    A a;
    a.a = 0;
    a.ptr = set_a;
    a.ptr(&a);
    printf("%d",a.a);

    getchar();
}
```

this is correct?
I really wonder
thanks

environment Language C on Visual studio 2012 on Windows 7

Comment: They're _all_ wrong, if only because of the fact that there's no documentation and your variable names are rubbish :-)

Comment: @kim taeyun - please clarify: 1) what (if any) error message are you getting, 2) what exactly do you believe is "incorrect" and 3) what are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Could you change the title of the question to something more descriptive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2nd and 3rd example you refer to `A` before (during) the declaration of it:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int (*ptr)(A*); // < the compiler doesn't know A at this point.
} A;
```

Also, in the 3rd example, you declare `ptr` as function that receives `A`, but then assign it with set_a which receives `A*`, which is not valid as well.

You need to declare it before:

```
struct A;
typedef struct A{
    int a;
    int (*ptr)(struct A*);
} A;
```

In the first example you refer to `F` which already exists so it is OK.

Comment: why are you indulging the OP such a vaguely worded question???  At the very least, he should have included an error message and the corresponding line #.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 - maybe because it didn't seem that vague to me. The question could have been more elaborated, though.

Comment: At the very least, the OP should have included an error message (e.g. `error: 'A' has no member named 'ptr'`) and the corresponding line number.  I think you did him a disservice by not asking for clarification.  IMHO...

Comment: look, I'm not the OP. Could this question be asked better? sure. Is it that bad to answer a question that should have been better asked? maybe. But it's not like a gave an answer when I didn't understand the question.